# running xjc on xsd, but class not generated

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, xsd

I have a xsd which contains the following entry:

```
 <xsd:simpleType name="Percentage">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="0"/>
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="1"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

but when I run xjc on this xsd I dont have class Percentage created. How can I do that and how will it work. I am writing code first web service in Java with CXF.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a binding file to force simpleType generation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html
You should try `javaType` declaration.

I only did enums before, so I can give you an example for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='sometype']//xs:element[@name='Percentage']/xs:simpleType">
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass name="Percentage"></jaxb:typesafeEnumClass>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

If you are using maven you should add these lines to the configuration of the jaxb plugin:

```
<bindingDirectory>src/main/schema</bindingDirectory>
<bindingIncludes>
   <include>**/*.xjb</include>
</bindingIncludes>
```

Comment: OK so I run the xjc command with Binding :                      <jxb:bindings version="1.0"
               xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="CBProjectionCommon.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
         <jxb:globalBindings mapSimpleTypeDef="true" />
  </jxb:bindings> 

</jxb:bindings>

Comment: that looks good to me :) this way is not working? then add this code to the question too...